# Advantage of oauth2 vs. simple login?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

If the goal is to provide login capabilities to various disconnected apps, is there an advantage to building it as an oauth2 provider (e.g. openid connect) vs. providing a simple login?

In other words, I see two options, each of which trigger a window from the various apps:

Option #1: "Sign in" opens a login page which prompts an oauth2 flow on the backend and ultimately returns success (with userid and access token) or fail. On success, the token is used for subsequent communication (i.e. to get profile data or whatever)

Option #2: "Sign in" opens a login page which simply checks the username/password against the database and returns success (with userid) or fail. On success, it creates a session for subsequent communication (i.e. to get profile data or whatever)

Is there any actual advantage to going with option #1? Assume that the third party apps are not open to the world, but collaborative projects which can use either method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With option 1 (OpenID Connect) you get

1. Single Sign On between each client application

   - Self explanatory
2. User-specific access tokens for communication with shared resources servers (APIs)

   - Assuming Option 2 (no OAuth), there wouldn't necessarily be any tokens (although there could be)...just a session cookie for each client app that is signed in.
3. An id token JWT that itself contains user information

   - Small benefit, but rather than authenticate and then request profile data (in option 2), with JWT you get profile data as part of your authentication response
4. A single authentication mechanism that separates that concern from each client application

   - In option 2, each client application needs to handle authentication with the DB. In option 1, the authorization server handles this in one place.

Comment: Wait- but I don't understand, with a regular ol' session don't you get all of that except single sign on? i.e. if they need to re-signon for each app, then due to the session they are still tracked by user id for all api calls....